# No response or error is coming when I try to schedule a meeting via Skype web sdk

Tags: javascript, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to schedule a meeting using the skype sdk. I've given the code same as shown in the samples. But I'm not getting any errors or any response from the code to schedule meeting. Please go through the codes and let me know if there is any errors in the code below. I'm stuck with this

```
    $('#authentication').click(function() {
        var client_id = "xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx";
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('client_id', client_id);
        var href = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=';
        href += client_id + '&resource=https://webdir.online.lync.com&redirect_uri=' + window.location.href;
        window.location.href = href;
    });
    $('#createmeeting').click(function() {
        var client;
        var conversation;
        var Application;
        console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('client_id'));
        Skype.initialize({ apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255' }, function (api) {
            Application = api.application;
            client = new Application();
            console.log('client created');
            var meeting = client.conversationsManager.createMeeting();
            meeting.subject('Planning meeting');
            meeting.expirationTime(new Date + 24 * 3600 * 5);
            meeting.onlineMeetingUri.get().then(uri => {
               var conversation = client.conversationsManager.getConversationByUri(uri);
               console.log(';'); // even this is not showing 
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
                 console.log(conversation);

        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            alert('Cannot load the SDK.');
        });            
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

new Date + 24 * 3600 * 5  ? 
result is "Thu May 16 2019 09:48:15 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)24 * 3600 * 5"

Answer (score 0):

You may have to perform sign in using `Application.signInManager.signIn`

```js
Skype.initialize({ apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255' }, api => {
      var app = new api.application;
      
      app.signInManager.signIn ({
        username: '****',
        password: '****'
      }).then(() => {
        console.log("signed in as",            app.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.displayName());
      }, err => {
        console.log("cannot sign in", err);
      });
    }, err => {
      console.log("cannot load the sdk package", err);
});
```